# Improper integral containing $\sqrt{\cos x-\frac1{\sqrt 2}}$ in the denominator

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How do I find the value of this integral--

$$I=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \frac{\sec^2 x \ dx}{\sqrt {\cos x-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}}}$$

I came across this integral too in physics.

Comment: The antiderivative does exist ! The fact that it is a monster is another story ! Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici How do we do it then?

Comment: I did not do it ! A CAS did it but it is really a monster; the same for the integral ($3.338953436$)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Do you know the closed form? I don't have mathematica or similar software and wolfram alpha doesn't provide the closed form

Comment: The closed form is apparently $$\frac{8 \Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{4}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{7}{4}\right) \, _3F_2\left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{7}{4};\frac{3}{2},\frac{9}{4};\frac{1}{2}\right)-5 \sqrt{2} \Gamma \left(-\frac{3}{4}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \, _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4};\frac{1}{2},\frac{7}{4};\frac{1}{2}\right)}{80 \sqrt{\pi }}+\frac{\pi }{\sqrt[4]{2}}$$, but the approximate numerical value is much more useful.

Comment: @user111187 Ohh that bad? The integral itself isn't such a monster, is it?

Comment: The indefinite integral is even worse (how could be simpler?). I can post it if you want, but I can't imagine it being useful.

Comment: @user111187 I mean the integral in the question (integrand)

Comment: @Pkwssis If it makes you feel any better, it's about $\pi+\arctan\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)$ :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With $t=\cos(x)$, we see it is an elliptic integral,
$$
I = \int_{1/\sqrt{2}}^1 \frac{dt}{t^2\sqrt{(1-t^2)(t-1/\sqrt{2})}}
$$

**added**

Maple gets: if $0<a<1$, then
$$
\int _{a}^{1}\!{\frac {dt}{{t}^{2}\sqrt { \left( 1-t^2 \right) 
 \left( t-a \right) }}}{}
=-{\frac {\sqrt {2}{\bf K} \left( 1
/2\,\sqrt {-2\,a+2} \right) }{a}}
+{\frac {\sqrt {2} \left( a+1
 \right) {\bf E} \left( 1/2\,\sqrt {-2\,a+2} \right) }{a
 \left( 1+a \right) }}
+\frac{1}{\sqrt {2}} \left( a+1 \right) {\bf \Pi} \left({\frac {a-1}{2a}},
\frac{\sqrt {-2\,a+2}}{2} \right) 
{a}^{-2}
$$
and in particular with $a=1/\sqrt{2}$,
$$
I = 2\,{\bf E} \left( 1/2\,\sqrt {2-\sqrt {2}} \right) -2\,{\bf K} \left( 1/2\,\sqrt {2-\sqrt {2}} \right) + \left( 1+\sqrt {2
} \right) {\bf \Pi} \left( 1/4\, \left( -2+\sqrt {2} \right) 
\sqrt {2},1/2\,\sqrt {2-\sqrt {2}} \right) \approx 3.338954
$$
where Maple's notation uses the modulus $k$.

Comment: I do not expect Cleo to post a proof. Have you got the same closed form as hers? Can you give more details?

Answer (score 13):

$$I=\frac\pi{\sqrt[4]2}+\sqrt{20-14\sqrt2}\ K\!\left(2\sqrt2-3\right)+\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}\ E\!\left(2\sqrt2-3\right)\\-2\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}\ \Pi\left(\sqrt2-1,\,2\sqrt2-3\right)$$
where $K(m), E(m), \Pi(n,m)$ are the [complete elliptic integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) of the first, second and third kind:
$$K(m)={\large\int}_0^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-m\sin^2\theta}}$$
$$E(m)={\large\int}_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1-m\sin^2\theta}\,d\theta$$
$$\Pi(n,m)={\Large\int}_0^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{\left(1-n\sin^2\theta\right)\sqrt {1-m\sin^2\theta}}$$
Note that this notation uses the parameter $m=k^2$ rather than the modulus $k$, that may differ from a convention used in other places.